# Content Encoding Error when connecting to LinkedIn oAuth

Tags: symfony, oauth, linkedin-api, hwioauthbundle

I have configured 2 providers and used the FOS-Oauth-Bridge. FB works just fine, but when I try connecting to LinkedIn, the browser shows the message

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an
>   invalid or unsupported form of compression.
>
> ```
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

I tried decoding the generated URL and that seems fine to:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=077-dd7c-4815-aea0-8c31e0ce7&scope=r_fullprofile&state=eecd50f81e6ad3e7e23cc11ec50d4768&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsf2test.dv%2Fapp_dev.php%2Fsec_area%2Flogin%2Fcheck-linkedin

I tried changing the redirect URL to 127.0.0.1, changing the port to 8X but nothing works

**I do not have SSL installed on my Windows / Apache**

When I manually change the LinkedIn URL to HTTP (instead of HTTPS), I get this message
Request denied

```
**Request denied**

    Sorry, we are unable to serve your request at this time due to unusual traffic from your network connection.

Reason codes:
3,2,19
```

Can someone help me figure out the problem?